# Free defined String Constants

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on an encryption application which implements an algorithm I made. I have about a year of experience in C and 6 months of experience in C++, but I have 6 years of experience in Visual Basic and Gambas (and I hope I'm a fast learner). I want to make my new application as efficient as possible; that's the reason I picked up C instead of C++ (I wanted to use a kind of lower-level language).

In my program, I'm using defined String constants to deal with error messages. I know that the preprocessor replaces the macro name with the actual string in every occurrence. If I'm not mistaken, this means that it pre-allocates the string constant and returns a different pointer for every occurrence. Do I have to free all those string pointers? Actually it seems a little odd... Are their pointers like automatic variables (which means that they are freed upon exit from scope) or do they stay forever as constants?

I use a dedicated header file called messages.h, which contains the definitions of every possible error message the program may use, so that I can change the Language etc. more easily; thus I can't write them as string constants directly. I thought of declaring them as constant variables, but then I either have to use a C file with the actual values and declare the header versions as extern, or have all the constants re-declared inside every file I include the messages.h header (believe me, I have more than 20 file consisting that project, and about 50-100 messages, plus the prompt messages — about 30 long ones — so it would consume considerable memory).

What do you suggest? Should — and more importantly can I — free the pointers to constants?

Comment: If they appear as string literals in the preprocessed source, then there's no need to free them (indeed, every reason not to free them) because they are not dynamically allocated.

Comment: And doesn't the accumulation of many instances of the same long string macro use up memory?

Comment: Only if the macro is used, and even then, it is in the text segment, not the data segment.  It depends on the form that you use to 'define' the messages.  If the header says `static const char message1[] = "blah";` in the header, then you are wasting space.  If it says `#define message1 "blah"`, you only incur the space when it is used.  If it says `extern const char message1[];` in the header, then you only have one copy of each string in the file that defines (as opposed to declares) the variables.

Comment: I use the #define way at the moment, as I think declaring global const variables would be more complex. So it's OK to do that? Is everything freed when exiting the corresponding function?

Comment: It's OK to use `#define`; the strings are created when they're used, and are allocated when the program starts and not changed thereafter, and are released when the program terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to C, I hope you never return to VB ;), ... macros, no, you don't have to free those "strings", and it doesn't returns a different pointer for every occurrence, take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR_MSG "Bla bla bla"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ERROR_MSG);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ERROR_MSG);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x40061c
0x40061c
```

As you can see the same address is printed.

Comment: It could return a different pointer each time.  The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says in Section 6.4.5 **String literals**: _It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
 appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined._  The arrays in question are those associated with string literals, of course.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That the definitive answer I needed... I read that the pre-processor instructions just replace things from inside the code, so I thought that when the compiler found two instances of the same message, it wouldn't be able to understand it's the same thing (it seems gcc is more clever than this)! Thanks very much!!! :D

Comment: So then we wander in the darkness?

Comment: OK, I think I might risk it... No matter what, it's better than declaring so many constants, isn't it? Does anyone have a better idea? Thank you all for answering!!! :)

Comment: you must consider the comment from @JonathanLeffler, anyway there is no risk if you don't try to modify those "string literals", compile always with `-Wall -pedantic`